# Can 奉 be attached to verbs I want to use?

Tags: particles

When 奉 is used as the sense of "politely", as the words 奉托, 奉告, which are usually used, can I attach 奉 to every verb that influences the other person? For example, what about 奉给 or 奉按摩?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

不能，Chinese used as the sense of "politely"，usually used 请 to every verb，For example 请给 or 请按摩，not used 奉给 or 奉按摩，
thanks，hahaha

Comment: So, is 奉 only used in traditional words?

Comment: @HarutoNagasaki, 奉 is only used in set phrases, like 奉托, 奉告, 奉劝，奉承，奉茶，奉上... ... but not work for all the verbs.

Comment: How can I differentiate words like that? For example, 好 can be attached to every verb as a role of -able : eatable, comfortable, etc. But some words can't be attached to every word but set words.

Comment: You might have to learn word by word I think. You can refer to the definition 3 in the link: http://www.zdic.net/z/17/js/5949.htm

Comment: You mean if there's the mark ~, it's only used as a set word?

Comment: @HarutoNagasaki: No, that is not the meaning of the mark ~. The mark ~ is commonly used in many dictionaries and is like a placeholder. It represents the word the dictionary entry is for. So in the link to zdic.net above, it's the entry for 奉, so “~” should be read as “奉”. Hope this helps.

Comment: This verb is a _bound morpheme_ in modern standard Mandarin. It is thus bound in set phrases and expressions, and should generally be learnt as they are.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite ancient-style, we don't use 奉 as "politely" any more today, except for several remaining set phrases, as dan listed.

Comment: Sounds very Japanese though, all this overdone politeness. I hear the Japanese language is full of that. If you insult someone in Japanese, is that also done politely?